# DEBUG: During Hook procedure call , it shows vsjitdebugger.exe error

Tags: c++, c, windows, hook, mousehover

My Application contains ole widgets.To handle ole widgets , I use mouse hook procedure to keep track the mouse click events.while closing the application , it provides some flickering and sometimes it shows the following errors

- Unable to use the location explorer.exe
- C:\Windows\System32\vsjitdebugger.exe  (Runtime error)

Regards,

karthik

Comment: Please provide detailed error info.

Comment: There's some highly unusual activity on this question/answer... be careful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution for this problem is as follows:

- problem may occur in the function `SetWindowsHookEx()`,
- you may made threadID as NULL in the function `SetWindowsHookEx()`.
  When you replace the NULL as currentthreadID, the runtimeerror is solved.